# When is ponerse valid to use as the equivalent of the English word "to become"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

I know `ponerse` can sometimes be used as the equivalent for the English phrase `to become` in the sense of `I became angry` --> `me puse enojado` but can it be used in the sense of `I want to to become a [name of career]` --> `quiero ponerse un [nombre de carrera]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's closer to think of it as equivalent to "getting" rather than "becoming".

You can say "Me pongo triste/contento", meaning "I get sad/happy". All uses I can think of it right now are related to emotional state.

> but can it be used in the sense of I want to to become a [name of career]

No, you'd never say "Me quiero poner médico" with that meaning, which translates in some possible context as "I want to get medic/medical".

There's also another use for the verb, I hope it's not too confusing to mention it too:

When you say "Me pongo en eso", meaning you are going to work on something (as in "I get to it").

Being not a linguist but just a speaker, I can't give much more precision.

Answer (score 1):

*Poner* is pretty complex to use. We normally use it when using *get*.

*I want to become...* can be translated as *quiero llegar a ser...*, or *quiero convertirme...* but the use of *poner* it's just wrong as follows:

> *I want to become a Lawyer*: *quiero ponerme un abogado*.

That's like saying *I want to put a Lawyer myself.*

So it's good to express emotions or adding adjectives to oneself like *I become smart* (me pongo inteligente), *I became disgusting* (me puse desagradable), etc.